# What will happen if I copy my browser cookies to another PC?

Tags: security, cookies, browser

Will I still be logged in in different sites or not?

For example gmail.com.

What kind of data does gmail save for logged in users?

Comment: Seems interested following

Comment: I think it's worth trying!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, If you copy the cookies from the source machine and save in another system, you will be logged in to your gmail account. In case the session is expired in the source machine, then these cookies are of no use. No one can access your gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. how hard it would be? Depends on what mechanism is used by Gmail to identify if it is the same browser.
Also it depends upon the expiry of the session, as the session expires the cookie is of no use.

You can see session/cookie hijacking https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking to know more about this.